# Best way to move around a 2d Array (Board Game)

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d-games

I am curious about what would be the easiest way to move around a 2d array in Java? I created a 2d array for a game board and use that to keep track of the positions of game pieces.  So if I have a 16x16 2d array how do I make it so players can move around the board X number of spaces.

I know the pieces would move from:

[0][0] -> [0][16] - TOP

then

[0][16] -> [16][16] - RIGHT SIDE

then

[16][16] -> [16][0] - BOTTOM

then finally back to the home space being [0][0].

[16][0] -> [0][0] - LEFT SIDE

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I wish I could accept multiple correct answers.... sigh ;(

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Do you have objects moving around these arrays? Are you keeping track of these objects' positions internally or externally? What's going on?

Comment: It is very unclear what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify that well, Yes, I want the objects to move around the array. But picture the 2d array like the board game Monopoly.  I keep track of there positions internally in there "GamePiece" class. The "BoardGame" class manages the pieces and sets their locations.  I am just not sure how to implement the rule so that if a player gets to space [0][16] how do I tell it to start moving downwards to [1][16].

Comment: I think there's no need for a 2d-array (256 elements), since you'd leave most of it empty. Why don't you just use a 1d-array (60 elements)? Rendering and game mechanisms are two different things.

Comment: There are actually some locations in the center that players can move to, I didnt mention that before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, you could implement your restriction on movement with the following pseudocode. I'm not 100% sure if this is what you want, but hopefully it's somewhat helpful

```
if (user tries to move right) {
    if (posX < 15 && posY == 0)
         //move right
    else
         //don't
}

if (user tries to move left) {
    if (posX > 0 && posY == 15)
         //move left
    else
         //don't
}
```

And so on. Is this similar to what you're looking for? Restrictions on array traversal? I'm assuming that your board only allows movement on the boundaries of the array based on what you say, so the following O positions are legal, and X are illegal:

```
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OXXXXXXXXXXXXXO
OXXXXXXXXXXXXXO
...
OXXXXXXXXXXXXXO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
```

Comment: Yes the boundaries, so I guess if I get to the boundary of the right side and still have a few more positions to move I would have to keep a count of the positions left to move and move accordingly once I make the switch to move down.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to keep in memory the count of positions left to move. Everything your movement logic needs is stored in your X- and Y-position variables for your game pieces. Implement a moveNext() algorithm which takes care of the work for you. You can overload the method with a moveNext(int k) { } method which itself calls moveNext() k-times, to advance the game piece k positions and it will take care of turns and everything else for you.

Answer (score 2):

You could hold the position of the player(s) in 2 variables, let's say `x` and `y`.

If it's a circular board game (from what I understand it is), you could have a function

```
advance_one_space() { //let's suppose it turns clockwise and your array is board[y][x]
    if ( y==0 && x<15 ) 
        x++;
    else if ( y<15 && x==15 ) 
        y++;
    else if ( y==15 && x>0 ) 
        x--;
    else if ( y>0 && x==0 ) 
        y--;
}
```

Calling this function 60 times would make the play make one turn, and maybe recieve 200$ :-)

And if you want to advance `n` spaces:

```
advance(n) {
    advance_one_space();
    if (n>1)
        advance(n-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment on your original question I understand that it's a matter of semantics.

From the player's point of view, the board isn't a matrix, as you implied, it's merely a straight line, that happens to "teleport" a player after the last position (16 * 4 = 64) to the first position.

And from the GameEngine point of view is a matter of converting the position on the line to a cell on the border of the matrix.

Thus, condider that your `GamePiece` object to have a `position` property, initialized with 0. The `BoardGame` has the property `boardSide` initialized with `16` and another property `boardLength` that's equals `boardSide * 4`.

Now, everytime your player tries to move you must ensure that it does not "fall off" the board, and then position it properly onscreen.

The code would be just like this:

```
// When updating the game state
private void move(GamePiece piece, int spaces) {
    int destination = piece.position + spaces;
    if (destination >= BoardGame.boardLength) {
        destination -= BoardGame.boardLength;
    }
    piece.position = destination;
}

// When updating the game view
private void updateView() {
    (...)
    // Considering you store the game pieces on the gamePieces collection
    for (GamePiece p: gamePieces) {
        int side = Math.floor(p.position % BoardGame.boardSide); // Either 0, 1, 2 or 3
        switch (side) {
            case 0: // Top
                // Place Piece method takes: the piece, the X position and the Y position
                BoardGame.placePiece(p, BoardGame.boardSide - p.position, 0);
                break;
            case 1: // Right

                break;
            case 2: // Bottom

                break;
            case 3: // Left
                break;
        }
    }
    (...)
}
```

**P.S.:** I'm much in a hurry right now and can't finish the code properly. Hope this helps, but I'll come back later and try to finish it.